# how to display Bas64 String values in the activity screen?

Tags: android

I have an audio file that i converted to Byte array. I convert the byte array in Base64. I want to display the Base64 values to the activity screen. but i don't know how. I am new to android, so your help will be very much appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to String and set to the TextView, having predefined it in layout.

```
TextView yourTextView = findById(R.id.text_view_id);
yourTextView.setText("your base 64 string");
```